# Kentor Saml authentication in load test environment

Tags: .net, performance-testing, saml-2.0, httpmodule, kentor-authservices

Using kentor httpmodule in our .net website , we have integrated authentication with common idp.

For local development we have setup stub idp provided by Kentor.

Now we are setting a Load test environment and have questions on how authentication should take place:

Shouldn't load tests ignore/mock authentication so we see correct time for page load, excluding login time. The reason why I am asking, this authentication managed by other team/third party, So we don't want to include in our application?

Should we modify Kentor code to return success mocked claims?

Any better approach to handle authentication during load/ performance test?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend removing sampler(s) related to login via [Filter Results Tool](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/FilterResultsTool/), it provides `--exclude-labels` parameter, you can filter out your "Login" requests using it.

You can install Filter Results Tool using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)

[image: JMeter Plugins Manager Filter Results]

Upon successful installation you should see `FilterResults.bat` and `FilterResults.sh` scripts allowing to trigger the tool on Windows or *nix environments correspondingly